# sqlalchemy orm - change column in a table depending on another table

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a 3 tables

table 1

```
| id  | name |
|:---:|:----:|
| 1   | name |
```

table 2

```
| id  | name | status |
|:---:|:----:|:------:|
| 1   | name |  True  |
```

table 3

```
| id_table1  | id_table2 | datetime | status_table2 |
|:----------:|----------:|:--------:|:-------------:|
|     1      |     1     |01/11/2011|     True      |
```

---

How I can change a status in table 2 when I create a link in table 3, with sqlalchemy ORM in python, status must be changed when link in table 3 created and also must be changed when link deleted, who have any cool and simple ideas?

Comment: Please use markup (`backticks`) to format your code as code. There is a help page right of your edit window.

Comment: If all access to this tables is done via sqlalchemy then you can probably use ORM Events sqlalchemy feature.

Comment: Otherwise I think the only solution is the trigger in postgres, or to listen to postgres events and do make appropriate actions, but in this case I don't think consistecy would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

solved problem by use ORM Events